# Why do my image rollovers not work on ipads and iphones?

Tags: html, css, iphone, ipad

I have found my image rollovers don't work on ipads or iphones. Does anyone know a work-around for these devices?
The rollovers are on this page:
http://www.newsite0914.i4dsign.co.uk/portfolio.html

Here is the CSS:

```
div.rollover div.mask {
   background-color: rgba(218, 220, 220);/* The Fallback */
   background-color: rgba(218,220,220, 0.8);
   width: 419px;
   height: 322px;
   padding:130px;
   margin:26px 28px 26px 28px;
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transform: translate(265px, 145px) rotate(45deg);
   -moz-transform: translate(265px, 145px) rotate(45deg);
   -o-transform: translate(265px, 145px) rotate(45deg);
   -ms-transform: translate(265px, 145px) rotate(45deg);
   transform: translate(265px, 145px) rotate(45deg);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}

div.rollover:hover div.mask {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transform: translate(-80px, -125px);
   -moz-transform: translate(-80px, -125px) ;
   -o-transform: translate(-80px, -125px);
   -ms-transform: translate(-80px, -125px) ;
   transform: translate(-80px, -125px) ;
}
```

I also apply overflow:hidden to each of the image divs with an image background:
eg.

```
div#hi_hats
{
    background-image: url("images/website_hiHats.jpg");
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is the HTML for an image rollover:

```
<div class="website_bck left" id="hi_hats">
                        <div class="rollover"> 

                            <div class="mask">
                                <h2>The Hi-Hats</h2>
                                <h3>Wedding & Function Band</h3>
                                <a href="portfolio_hi_hats.html">More Information</a>
                            </div>

                        </div>      
                    </div>
```

Comment: because you can't hover on an ipad?

Answer (score 0):

Most touch based devices' browsers fire :hover rules when you tap on an element. Assuming you know this and that you consider this to be wanted behaviour, here's your problem:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) 
and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (min-device-width: 320px) 
div.rollover div.mask {
   padding: 5%!important;
}
```

(main.css:2884)

The padding you've specified in your original rule (padding:130px;) gets replaced with the above one on devices like smartphones and tablets. If you remove this rule the roll-over effect works as it does on desktop, but through tapping.

It does work with the margin being 5%, but the mask gets placed in such a way that most of it gets clipped on mobile devices.

I debugged this problem using Chrome's inspector and its "device mode".

Comment: Thanks very much for going to this trouble. Ironically I added in the padding 5% specifically for smartphones and tablets as I hoped this might help stop the text disappearing on smaller devices.